# How to raise a custom error code in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, sinatra

I did the following in my sinatra app:

```
disable :show_exceptions
disable :raise_errors

error do
  haml :error, :locals => {:error_message => request.env['sinatra.error'].to_s}
end

get '/error' do
  raise "ERROR!!"
end
```

If I visit `/error` I get a `500 - Internal Server Error` response code, which is god and wanted. But how do I change the code to, eg, 404 or 501?

**The answer:**

```
disable :show_exceptions
disable :raise_errors

get '/error' do
  halt(404,haml(:error, :locals => {:error_message => request.env['sinatra.error'].to_s}))
end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like `raise 404` raises an error just like `raise ZeroDivisionError` would, which causes your app to throw a 500 Internal Server Error. The simplest way to return a specific error is to use `status`

```
get '/raise404' do
    status 404
end
```

You can also add a custom response body with `body`

```
get '/raise403' do
    status 403
    body 'This is a 403 error'
end
```

Comment: ok that works. but how do I stop the request, because if there's a view to be rendered at the end of the route sinatra renders it, even if I set the status and body as you've done it in your answer.

Comment: got it! use ```halt STATUS, BODY``` ;)

Answer (score 6):

I use this in block

```
if 'condition'  then 
   do something
else 
   halt 500  , "error message"
end 
#only without error
erb :my_template
```

In case of error my log is like this 
HTTP/1.1" 500 13 0.1000

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `raise "ERROR!!"`, try just doing `error 404` or `error 501` with optional status message after the status code.

Update: 
If you define your error handler as 
`error 400..501 do...` for example, you can use `error 501 "ERROR!!"` in your `"/error"` route. This will also put your "ERROR!!" message in   `env['sinatra.error'].message`.

Comment: wait, what doesn't work is to get error to render my ```:error``` view correctly, how do I access the error message (in my example "ERROR!!") ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the message issue. Short of that, we can explore raising custom errors which may be of benefit as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work :/ (I had to use ```error 501, "ERROR!!"```) I get a nil class for ```env['sinatra.error'].message```